# Does Selenium require maximized browser window?

Tags: browser, selenium

I have not used Selenium myself, but I was wondering whether the browser window needs to be maximized during test execution? I have used some other tools where the mouse pointer does not find the correct HTML element if the window is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Selenium 2.0 (WebDriver) automatically attempts to scroll an element into view when you're going to perform any action on this element. If it can't scroll it throws an exception. So, don't make your window too small, but there is no need to maximize it. Keep it "mid-size".
2. For the abovementioned reason, you may want to maximize the browser window to avoid excessive scrolling, that can cause some unnecesssary events on the page.
3. Sometimes Selenium (WebDriver) can't click an element if it is placed too close to the viewport border (half-visible). In this case you can try to tune the window size to make this element either totally visible, or totally invisible (to activate auto-scrolling).
4. If you use Selenium (WebDriver) with "native events" enabled, you'd better keep the browser window in foreground and in focus during test execution. No matter whether it is maximized or "mid-size" -- just don't minimize it!

   If you're happy with "synthesized events" -- many chances for your tests to run successfully in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

No, because Selenium uses the DOM Structure to act on and not the OS(mouse, windows and stuff). You can actually minimize your window during a test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not maximized, but probably best to have test at set minimum and maximum size.

An idea would be to have selenium resize the window for you before it runs the tests... A quick search gave me this: https://makandracards.com/makandra/9773-how-to-start-selenium-browser-with-custom-window-size